# Unable to write JSONValue into NSDictionary - JSON Framework not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am using JSON to receive response and then trying to save it in `NSDictionary`. I am using same code in almost 12 clones of same app and its working great. But, in one of my app, I am unable to do this.

```
    NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [jsonString JSONValue];
    NSString *statusString = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"status"];
```

This a simple two line code and works fine normally, but I don't know whats going on this time. May be my JSON Framework is not working properly. But I am getting this in `JSONValue`:

```
{
"status": "Success",
"data": [
    {
        "userName": "abc@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "ABC",
        "last_name": "XYZ",
        "gender": "male",
        "userid": 1,
        "membershipStatus": "Active",
        "Saldo": 499.749,
        "Avatar": "no_photo.gif",
        "uniqueCode": "abc234abc234",
        "registerKey": "abc543abc534",
        "eMail": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

}

Still, when I execute it, I get this error:

```
[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Because `resultDictionay` is empty.

Why `resultDictionay` is empty? Any suggestion?

Comment: please check that you get dictionary from server using if([jsonString JSONValue]isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary Class])

Comment: I am getting NSString from server and same string for other clones. Still working there fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
[jsonString JSONValue];
```

set target dependencies in your project follow by this link

[Parsing json in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318471/parsing-json-in-an-ios-app)

JSONValue is thridParty libiary from SBJson. Apple have in-built framework for convert json use this approach

use this

```
NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
strResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"returnString : %@",strResponse);


NSData *responseData = [strResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    tempDict = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
}
```